# Remove blocked users from chat messages list

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of all messages like this which contains the user id who sent it

```
$messages= Chat::all();
```

And a list of blocked users like this with the id of the user who was blocked

```
$blockedUsers=BlockUser::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

My question is **How to remove a message if the user id of the message exist in the blocked list?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all messages of a blocked user you can do it in the following way.

```php
if ($blockedUsers = BlockUser::pluck('id')) {
    $messages = Chat::whereNotIn('user_id', $blockedUsers)->get();
}
```

It should be noted that there are many ways to do this, directly with 1 single query doing Subqueries, but this will be enough to solve your problem and you will understand it much better, the other ways require a deeper knowledge of the framework.

Comment: no thats not what I needed I dont want to delete it from the database, I want to remove it only from the respose

Comment: I have edited my answer for your benefit

Comment: first of all sorry for my many questions and I will accept your answer for your effort but there is a last thing I need which I mentioned the blocked users is a list and not a single user

Comment: I have edited the question again. Next time you need to be clearer about what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The filter messages, blocked users

```
public function getMessages(): JsonResponsive 
{
  $messages = Chat::where('user_id', '!=', $blockedUserId)->get();

  return response()->json($messages)
}
```